# React (Native) - is it possible to converting class component with static into functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a custom component called `FlixToast` using class component long time ago

`FlixToast.js`

```js
export default class FlixToast extends React.PureComponent {
  animation = new Animated.Value(0);
  constructor() {
    super();
    FlixToast.Flix = this;
    this.state = {
      toastList: [],
    };
  }
  
  // here i have a static method that need to be called globally
  static show(message, options) {
    FlixToast.Flix.show(message, options);
  }

  show(message, options) {
    const id = new Date().getTime().toString();
    const onClose = () => {
      this.hide(id);
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.setState({
        toastList: [
          // ...this.state.toastList,
          {message, key: id, onClose, ...options},
        ],
      });
    });
  }

  hide(id) {
    this.setState({
      toastList: this.state.toastList.filter(t => t.key !== id),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'position' : undefined}
        style={styles.containerView}
        pointerEvents="box-none"
      >
        {this.state.toastList.map((el, index) => (
          <Toast {...el} />
        ))}
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

usually i call this render in `App.js` like this

`App.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import FlixToast from './path-of-my-flixtoast'
import MainApp from './path-of-my-MainApp'

const App = props => {
  return (
    <>
      <MainApp/>
      <FlixToast/>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

so, everytime i want to show `Toast` i only need to call the `show` `method` **without** importing the `FlixToast` component like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import FlixToast from './path-of-my-flixtoast'

const Home = props => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    FlixToast.show('Welcome user')
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

---

Main Issue:

I want to convert `FlixToast` class based component into functional component, but i have a problem about converting the `static` method into function that can be called globally, is it possible?
any idea would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use the [useImperativeHandle](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) hook. This hook allows you to access a function from a child component to a parent component.

Example:

```
import React, { useRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    },
  }));

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Child Component</Text>
      <TextInput ref={inputRef} />
    </View>
  );
});

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef();

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Focus Input" onPress={() => childRef.current.focus()} />
      <ChildComponent ref={childRef} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: I want to avoid declaring my toast component inside return of other component like my 3rd code above, i only need to import toast and call its function directly

Comment: what do you want, without import, you can't show anything, or if you want to convert the class to a function use useImperativeHandle instead of static in the function-based component